# Get the X-B3-TraceId from Request in the Spring Boot Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-sleuth

Im trying to get the Traceid in the request in the configured filter in the spring boot application for the auditing.

```
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
 log.info("X-B3-TraceId Id in request:: {}", httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-B3-TraceId"));
         }
```

How can we get the Traceid from the request in the filte

Answer (score -1):

When i deploy the application in PCF . Im able to get the trace id from the header for the incoming request